# rsync deploy and file/directories permissions

Tags: permissions, rsync, chmod

I'm trying to use rsync to deploy my website that resides on a shared web host.

Phpsuexec is running on it and that caused me problems with permissions on files and directories I've transfered via rsync. Actually files should be set to 644 and directories to 755, otherwise I get a 500 error.

After several attempts, I came with this rsync command:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --chmod=Du=rwx,go=rx,Fu=rw,og=r -p --exclude-from=/var/www/mylocalfolder/.rsyncignore /var/www/mylocalfolder/ user@mywebsite.net:~/
```

Unfortunately this command doesn't works as expected because all the sent directories have been set to 744. On the other hand, files permission have been correctly set on 644.

I can't understand what is wrong.

P.S. I use Linux on my local machine.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If so, please share, as I'm having the exact same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `-p` option: it is implied by `-a` which is an alias for `-rlptgoD` ([source](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rsync.htm)).

Answer (score 49):

Try it like this :

```
--chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This works for me.  I wanted to do 770 for directories and 660 for files, which works with this flag: --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rwx,Do=,Fu=rw,Fg=rw,Fo=

Comment: If you already have the desired permissions in numerical form, you can use a shorter `--chmod=D0770,F0660`

Comment: I think you also need to check that `--perms` is passed, and that the current user has permission to change the permissions of that file.

Comment: To set the permissions on a file or folder to none for a specific group you can simply assign nothing after the `=` symbol.
For example, to set the directory permissions to 750 and the file permissions to 640 you can use the following:
`rsync --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,D=,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo= --recursive ~/my/old/location ~/my/new/location`
**if you do not specifically set permissions, they will be set to whatever the source permissions are**